# getDrawingCache is not working for LibGdx

Tags: android, bitmap, libgdx

I wanted to take a screenshot of my gameview using Android's `getDrawingCache`.

But all i get was an Blank Image.

I know `LibGDX` provides its own classes for Taking ScreenShots.

But why is this method not working for a `LibGDX` view.I checked it for all other views and it works fine.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gameView=initializeForView(new TalkingFriendApp(this), cfg);
gameView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

}

public void takeScreenShot()
{
 Bitmap b=gameView.getDrawingCache();
 b.writeBitmapToFile("dance/abc.png");
}
```

`writeBitmapToFile(String path)` is my function used to write Bitmap to Storage Drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SurfaceView` -- and, by extension, `GLSurfaceView` (which LibGDX uses) -- does not support `getDrawingCache()` because it does not draw within the normal view system.

See this thread on Google Groups for an explanation:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-platform/xHIActZZ9PA